# How old are the human protagonists of the Bartimaeus series?

Tags: bartimaeus

Bartimaeus himself, of course, has a several-thousand-year-long history of service to magicians on Earth, and an indefinite period spent in the Other Place before that. But what about the other two viewpoint characters in the *Bartimaeus* series, Nathaniel (aka John Mandrake) and Kitty Jones?

We know, of course, that in the 2nd book Nathaniel becomes

> the youngest Cabinet minister ever.

But how old is he exactly during the events of *The Amulet of Samarkand*, *The Golem's Eye*, and *Ptolemy's Gate*? And what of Kitty, his sometime nemesis and Resistance firebrand? I'm curious as to whether she's older or younger than him, and can't remember any conclusive statement either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adamant's answer pins down Nathaniel's age very well, but for Kitty's we need to resort to [online Word of God](http://bartiforums.com/topic/6639692/1/):

> How old was Kitty? I think about 15. She's about a year older than Nat, I think, which makes her about 18 in PG, and about 15 in GE, which took place 3 years earlier.
>
> <sub>-- Jonathan Stroud</sub>

So:

- In *The Amulet of Samarkand*, **Nathaniel is 12 and Kitty is 13.**
- In *The Golem's Eye*, **Nathaniel is 14 and Kitty is 15.**
- In *Ptolemy's Gate*, **Nathaniel is 17 and Kitty is 18.**

Answer (score 5):

### Nathaniel

During the most of the events of *The Amulet of Samarkand*, Nathaniel is twelve:

> The article was on page two, sandwiched between the Employment
> Ministry’s monthly request for new apprentices and a short report from
> the Italian campaign. It was three columns in length. It noted with
> regret the deaths in a severe house fire of the Internal Affairs
> Minister Arthur Underwood and his wife, Martha. The blaze had started
> at approximately 10:15 P.M. and had only been fully extinguished by
> fire crews and emergency service magicians three hours later, by which
> time the whole building had been gutted. Two neighboring houses had
> been badly affected, and their occupants evacuated to safety. The
> cause of the fire was unknown, but police were keen to interview Mr.
> Underwood’s apprentice, **John Mandrake, aged twelve**, whose body had not
> been recovered.
>
> <sub>—*The Amulet of Samarkand*</sub>

During *The Golem’s Eye*, he is fourteen:

> More than two years had passed since the time of Lovelace’s rebellion,
> and the sudden emergence of Nathaniel into the elite. **By now, he was
> fourteen years old**, taller by a head than when he had returned the
> Amulet of Samarkand to the protective custody of a grateful
> government; bulkier, too, but still lean-framed, with his dark hair
> hanging long and shaggy around his face after the fashion of the day.
>
> <sub>—*The Golem’s Eye*</sub>

And finally, during *Ptolemy’s Gate*, he is seventeen:

> John Mandrake was an attractive young man, and the scent of power hung
> about him, sweet and intoxicating, like honeysuckle in the evening
> air. He was of medium height, slender of body, and swift and confident
> in action. His pale, slim face presented an intriguing paradox,
> combining extreme youth—**he was still only seventeen years old**—with
> experience and authority.
>
> <sub>—*Ptolemy’s Gate*</sub>

Well, that was easy.

### Kitty

Figuring out Kitty’s age is a little harder. She seems to be somewhat older than Nathaniel. During the account of how she joined the Resistance, she is mentioned as being thirteen:

> She and Nicholas, a stocky young man with a brooding manner, had
> worked for Mr. Pennyfeather since they were children. The rest of the
> company were younger; no one older than eighteen. Kitty and Stanley,
> both thirteen, were the youngest of all.
>
> <sub>—*The Golem’s Eye*</sub>

She’s mentioned as being fifteen some time later:

> Time passed. Kitty left school at the standard age of fifteen.
>
> <sub>—*The Golem’s Eye*</sub>

So she was probably thirteen during *The Amulet of Samarkand*, but she could conceivably have been fourteen. Her age during the other books is more or less a simple matter of incrementing: if she was about thirteen during the first book, for example, she would have been about 18 during the last one.